# Count only alphanumeric characters in a string

Tags: r, text, tidytext

Given the string `"This has 4 words!"` I would like to count only the letters and digits. I would like to exclude whitespace and punctuation. As such, the string above should return `13`.

I'm not sure why, but I cannot get this for R.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `[[:alnum:]]` in `str_count` to count only the alphabets and digits

```
library(stringr)
str_count(str1, "[[:alnum:]]")
#[1] 13
```

---

Or in `base R` with `gsub` to remove the `[[:punct:]]` and then get the number of characters with `nchar`

```
nchar(gsub("[[:punct:]]+", "", str1))
```

Or negate (`^`) characters that are not alpha numeric, replace with blank (`""`) and get the `nchar`

```
nchar(gsub("[^[:alnum:]]+", "", str1))
#[1] 13
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "This has 4 words!"
```

Comment: Thank you! That was on the tip of my tongue!